# "Body tissues" or "body's tissues"?

Tags: possessives

How can I determine what's the correct way to use the [possessive 's](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine) in cases like the following one?

> "Body tissues"

or

> "body'**s** tissues"?

I'm always confused in that and I would like to know a way how to determine correctly whether to use possessive 's or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Body's tissues** would mean that the *body owns the tissues.* **Body tissues** means that the *tissues are for a body*(or of the body variety). It wouldn't make sense for the body to own a tissue in most situations, so body tissues is most likely the correct term to use.

Summary (in English grammar terms): In body's tissues, **body** is a **[possessive noun](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-1/nouns/lesson-8/possessive-nouns)**. In body tissues, **body** is an **[adjective](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adjective?q=ADJECTIVE).**

Comment: Summary: In body's tissues, **body is a possessive noun**. In body tissues, **body is an adjective.**

Comment: Absolutely. I'll add that summary into the actual answer:)